# error: storage size of 'status' isn't known, which header am I missing?

Tags: c

I get this error when I run "make install"

```
 ==> COMPILING "OBJ/x86_64-linux-cc/spawn.o"
spawn.c: In function 'wait_chld':
spawn.c:206:9: error: storage size of 'status' isn't known
  WAIT_T status;
         ^~~~~~
```

```
EXPORT int
wait_chld(pid)
        int     pid;
{
        int     died;
        WAIT_T  status;

        do {
                do {
                        died = wait(&status);
                } while (died < 0 && geterrno() == EINTR);
                if (died < 0)
                        return (died);
        } while (died != pid);

        if (WCOREDUMP(status))
                unlink("core");

        return (WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

I'm a novice at this and am not sure where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not missing any header. Just get rid of `WAIT_T` and use `int` instead. The documentation for `wait` doesn't say anything about `WAIT_T`, so I'm not sure where you got it from in the first place.